# is there a way to add blocks to NSOperationQueue like this

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, block

I am trying to understand NSOperationQueue's and am trying to create the most simple example possible. I have the following:

```
NSOperationQueue *myOQ=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[myOQ addOperationWithBlock:^(void){
  NSLog(@"here is something for jt 2");
}];
[myOQ addOperationWithBlock:^(void){
  NSLog(@"oh is this going to work 2");
}];
```

But would like to do this:

```
void  (^jt)() = ^void(){
  NSLog(@"here is something for jt");
};

void (^cl)() = ^void(){
  NSLog(@"oh is this going to work");
};

NSOperationQueue *myOQ=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[myOQ addOperation:jt];
[myOQ addOperation:cl];
```

Is this latter form possible? Can I convert a block to an NSOperation?

thx in advance

Comment: No that won't work, but why do you even want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: just learning with simple example: this was also helpful but read the comments too http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could:

```
NSBlockOperation *jtOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"here is something for jt");
}];

NSBlockOperation *clOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"oh is this going to work");
}];

[myOQ addOperation:jtOperation];
[myOQ addOperation:clOperation];
```

Having said that, I'd generally do `addOperationWithBlock` unless I really needed the `NSOperation` object pointers for some other reason (e.g. to establish dependencies between operations, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do

```
[operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    // Stuff
})];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
let networkingOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {
                             // Your code here
                          })
```

Comment: Your solution is tempting, but you should never use `NSBlockOperation` wrapping an _asynchronous_ function, like a network request. Rather, properly subclass `NSOperation`. `NSOperationQueue` is meant to execute asynchronous tasks aka `NSOperation` instances. The `NSBlockOperation` is simply a helper where you can enqueue a _synchronous_ operation. In that case, however, you would be almost always better off using dispatch queues.